# Jquery color on hover randomize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a 5x5 div matrix with the starting color brown.On every refresh it should make 7 random colors like the code below.My question is how can i make it so on every refresh it places 4 of each 6 diferent colors in the hover function and the 7th color in the last free div?
full code here->http://pastebin.com/tUxB5usi

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var b = 15;
            var Otv = "Отворени: ";
            var c = 3;
            var Prom = "Промени: ";
            document.getElementById('otvoreni').innerHTML = Otv + b;
            document.getElementById('promeni').innerHTML = Prom + c;
            var f="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            var f1="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            var f2="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            var f3="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            var f4="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            var f5="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            var f6="#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999);
            $(".inner").hover(function() {
                if (b > 0) {
                    $(this).css("background-color", f);
                    b--;
                    document.getElementById('otvoreni').innerHTML = Otv + b;
                };
            }, function() {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#B87333");
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Generate a random index (random * 6) and store that in a variable. Use that index in your div and run a loop excluding the array value that matches that index (using if)

Comment: What i forgot to mention is that even the places in which the 7 colors are placed should be randomized.About the color placement randomization i got that tyvm.

Comment: Can you please clarify how many boxes do you need to assign a color to? First you mention a 5x5 matrix, so I guess there you have 25 divs, while later on you say "the 7th color in the last free div", which implies that you have 7 divs..

Comment: I meant to say there are 25 divs in which 6(colors)x4(of each)=24 divs and the last free div has the 7th color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking @Chop solution, I did the last square to don't be the same always.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var b = 15;
    var Otv = "Отворени: ";
    var c = 3;
    var Prom = "Промени: ";
    document.getElementById('otvoreni').innerHTML = Otv + b;
    document.getElementById('promeni').innerHTML = Prom + c;
    var colors = {1:["red",4],2:["blue",4],3:["green",4],4:["gray",4],5:["orange",4],6:["purple",4],7:["black",0]}

    function selectColor(index){
        var noColor=true;
        while(noColor){
            if(colors[index][1]>0){
                colors[index][1]=colors[index][1]-1;
                noColor=false;
                return index;
            }else{
                index = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
            }
        }
    }

    function setEventHandlers(element, index){
        element.on("mouseenter",function(e){
            var color = colors[index][0];
            $(this).css("background-color", color);
        });
        // element.on("mouseleave",function(e){
            // $(this).css("background-color", "#B87333");
        // });
    }

    var winner = Math.floor(Math.random()*24);
    var elements = $(".inner");
    for(var y = 0; y < elements.length; y++){
        var element = elements.eq(y)
        if(y == winner) setEventHandlers(element,7)
        else setEventHandlers(element, selectColor(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6)))
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way

```
var colors = []
for(var x = 0; x < 7; x++){
    //Fill the array with random colors
    colors.push("#B"+Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999))
}

//Remove the last color and store it in a separate variable
var lastColor = colors.splice(colors.length - 1, 1)

//Function for array shuffling
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};

function setEventHandlers(element, index, last){
    //If this is the last element, then use the 7th color, otherwise pick the color at index
    if (last) var color = lastColor
    else var color = colors[index]

    //Set up the event handlers with the chosen color
    element.on("mouseenter",function(e){
        $(this).css("background-color", color);
    })
    element.on("mouseleave",function(e){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#B87333");
    })
}

//Store all elements with class inner in the variable elements
var elements = $(".inner")

//Loop through the elements array
for(var y = 0; y < elements.length; y++){
    var element = elements.eq(y)

    //If the loop has gone once through all colors, shuffle the colors array
    if(y % 6 == 0) colors = shuffle(colors)

    //If the index equals 24, that means we are at the last element, we call the setEventHandlers with attribute index = 0 (won't be used anyways) and last set to true
    if(y == 24) setEventHandlers(element, 0, true)

    //If not the last square, then call setEventHandlers for the current element with index = current index modulo 6 (# of colors), which will always be an integer in the [0,5] range
    else setEventHandlers(element, y % 6, false)
}
```

Comment: The color placement in the div should be in a randomized place not in a diagonal pattern.

Comment: Updated my post to randomize the color assignment

Comment: Now it's better but there's one last thing,each of the 6 colors should be placed only 4 times and the remaining one on the remaining div.In your code one color appears more than 4 times.Like i said 6(different colors)x4(of each color)=24 divs and the last remaining color for the last remaining free div.

Comment: Tyvm that worked fine.If it ins't too much trouble as to explain what does what that would be helpful because i only know what half of the code does.

Comment: Tyvm that helped alot.